# Java / OrientDB console.bat seems to buffer input

Tags: java, orientdb, windows-console

Recently I upgraded my Java installation to 1.8.0_25:

```
C:\orientdb-community-1.7.9\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

First of all, OrientDB server is fine with my java version. However console.bat has now a very anoying behavior. Whatever I type will only become visible after I hit enter. Before the upgrade each character would become visible as soon as I enter it. Somehow the console echo seems to be buffered now.

How can I get the old unbuffered behavior back? How can I tell console.bat to show characters as I type along?

Comment: Well I don't really understand the issue. Could you create a screenshot. Because I also have trouble with OrientDB console. https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3003 But I think my issue might be a bit different, or not? I have latest OrientDB but Java 1.7. So it might not be a 1.8 issue. Please deliver a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: A screenshot would not really help here. What you see is "empty input". As long as I type I see no echo. As soon as I hit enter I see what I have typed. The console accepts all editing commands incl. backspace or cursor movements (I tested this). However I am basically blind. Right now I prepare the statements in an editor and paste them into the console. Not really convenient :(

Comment: Is still present the issue? Have you tried with other version of OrientDB?